# Rails 4 delete button logs me out and results in "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm running Rails 4.2, Devise 3.4.1, and CanCan 1.6.10. When I try to delete resources via a standard delete button like the following one, I get signed out and redirected to the login page.

`<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="btn-alert" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/admin/lots/6">Delete</a>`

My dev log tells me it's because it "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity". The only way I can seem to get this to work is to change from a delete button to a form that posts to the delete action, but that's kind of dumb. I've done this in other Rails 4 apps so I'm pretty sure I'm doing it right.

**index.html.erb**

```
<% if can? :destroy, lot %>
   <%= link_to "Delete", admin_lot_path(lot.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'btn-alert' %>
<% end %>
```

**lots_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::LotsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def destroy
    @lot.destroy
    redirect_to admin_lots_path, notice: "Lot was successfully removed."
  end
end`
```

Like I said, replacing the button with a form seems to work but this isn't ideal.

```
<%= form_for([:admin, lot], method: :delete) do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit value: "Delete", class: 'btn-standard', data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
<% end %>
```

If I comment out `before_filter :authenticate_user!` and `load_and_authorize_resource` from the controller it works. I'm assuming the csrf token is not being sent along with this request like it would be in a form.

Does anybody have any ideas on what I can try? Willing to post more code if it would be helpful. This happens on all deletes in my application btw.

**Update**: Here's a snippet from development.log

```
Started DELETE "/admin/lots/6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-26 15:03:22 -0500
Processing by Admin::LotsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"6"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

Comment: Might be you're missing the proper JavaScript support for Rails UJS. Are you sure you have `application.js` loaded correctly?

Comment: Yep, I've got `//= require jquery_ujs` in there

Comment: Any unusual JavaScript errors? Does your POST request look okay, like it contains the CSRF token? Network inspector helps here.

Comment: can you show your log?

Comment: Everything in the network panel looks good, 302 response, POST with a hidden input of `_method: "delete"` being sent.

Comment: Make sure you have `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` somewhere in your layout (most likely in application.html.erb).

Comment: AFAIK this is not required in Rails 4. If I view source on a form I can see it's automatically injected. However, I've tried this and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `button_to` instead of `link_to`.

```rb
button_to "Delete", admin_lot_path(lot.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'btn-alert'
```

`link_to` produces this HTML which is missing the authenticity token,

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="btn-alert" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/admin/lots/6">Delete</a>
```

while `button_to` produces

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/admin/lots/6">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    <input data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="btn-alert" type="submit" value="Delete">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="1QajBKKUzoEtUqi6ZX8DsQtT9BfvKY/WVXAr4lu4qb+iLGMkLlsviNcctlGxyq+VrsMa+U9vmb4PAdaRFDKZVQ==">
</form>
```

Comment: I'll take that. It still produces a form but at least it's a one liner. I'm still confused as to why link_to doesn't work. I understand it doesn't provide the csrf token but I've done this in the past. Maybe it worked in Rails 3 and not Rails 4?

Comment: Ryan, do you have `= csrf_meta_tags` in your `head` tag? _(edit: I realised you did refer to it above. I'm pretty sure this is still required in Rails 4 for jQuery UJS to send the authenticity token on non-GET requests.)_

Comment: Sigh. After getting it all working with the button_to solution I saw your response and thought I'd try adding the `csrf_meta_tags` to the head agin and sure enough, it works now. Thanks for making me double check, I much prefer this solution.

Comment: After seeing your first comment I went to check my own app, and sure enough, I was using `a` tags for the sign out buttons that use method:delete. Further digging led me to check whether the csrf tags were still used. Glad that you've solved the mystery!

Comment: Right, I knew I had other apps using a tags for delete methods, which is why I was banging my head against the wall.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the csrf token as a parameter, example:

```
link_to "Delete", admin_lot_path(id: lot.id, authenticity_token: form_authenticity_token), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'btn-alert'
```

"form_authenticity_token" is a convention method that returns the CSRF token. That will authenticate the request.

Answer (score -1):

As per [ActionController documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html) all the Controller actions are protected from CSRF(Cross Site Request Forgery ) attacks, so either you need to include your token in rendered HTML or the other way is to include
`protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }` in your **Application controller** . This problem doesn't comes in  **GET** request as you are not manipulating data over there but comes in **POST,DELETE,PATCH** methods.